# how to know the run time a function is taking in a program in seconds?

Tags: c

on some competitive programming sites, I came across the time a function is taking. Now I am concerned is there any method to measure the time a function takes in execution in C?

Comment: What platform are you using to run your program?

Comment: These sites are probably running in a very different hardware and software environments than yours, so I doubt that you will measure the same time as the sites do.

Answer (score 2):

```
int start = os_call_to_get_time();
func();
int end = os_call_to_get_time();
printf("call took %d secs\n", end  - start);
```

in real life you probably want to do it in milli- or microseconds. Or execute the function several thousand times

Answer (score 0):

You should use struct timeval for this purpose.

void funtion()

```
 {

 struct timeval t1,t2;

 gettimeofday(&t1,Null);

 //Functionality

 gettimeofday(&t2,Null);

 //Print the difference

 }
```

This code can run on windows and linux